# How to toggle view visibility with bindingAdapter based on function return in viewModel

Tags: kotlin

I have written a bindingAdapter to toggle the visibility based an a return value from a function which sits in the viewModel. For some reason it is not working.

All the answers I found so far did not help.

Any help is much appreceated.

> BindingAdapter.kt:

```
package com.ronnabyte.dutytime.util

import android.view.View
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter

@BindingAdapter("app:visibleGone")
fun showHideView(view: View, show: Boolean) {
    view.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

> custom_row.xml:

```
...

  <data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.ronnabyte.dutytime.viewmodel.DutyDayViewModel" />
</data>

...

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/md_theme_light_surfaceTint"
    app:visibleGone="@{viewModel.lastDutyDay}"
    android:orientation="vertical">

...
```

> ListFragment.kt

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private val viewModel: DutyDayViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    _binding?.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    return binding.root
}
```

> ViewModel.kt:

```
    fun isLastDutyDay(): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

I know the function is not doing anything apart from returning true, the logic would follow later, it is just to see if my bindingAdapter is working, which is not...